# Creating your own html method to extract a tag

Tags: java, html

### Rules I can't use anything from the HTML library need to make method from scratch.

Given a text file with text like `<name> brain </name>  <job> evil scientist </job>` and I need to extract the information in between the html `<>` and get the tag. My method keeps returning array out of bounds exceptions and I'm unsure how to fix methods.

```
public static String extractTagContent(String html, String tag) {
    String list = "";
    while (html.contains("</" + tag + ">")) {
        list += html.substring(html.indexOf("<" + tag + ">") + tag.length() + 1, html.indexOf("</" + tag + ">")) + "\n";

        html = html.substring(html.indexOf("<" + tag + ">") + tag.length() + 3);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: I meant StringIndexOutOFBoundException not array out of bounds

Comment: If you can't use any HTML libraries, you could still use the Java XML library ;-)

Comment: I think you need to read Eric Lippert's excellent  [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) article.

Comment: text file has content '<name> brain </name>  <job> evil scientist </job>'   what value will tag take in? what's expected output?

Comment: for each category like name i just need to output brian

Comment: How could i modify the code so that it will work in situations like  
<name> brian <job> </name> evil scientist</job> And i want the same results prints out brain and the evil scientist thanks for help the code works, but not in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

fixed this two lines inside the loop

```
list += html.substring(html.indexOf("<" + tag + ">") + tag.length() + 2, html.indexOf("</" + tag + ">")) + "\n";
html = html.substring(0, html.indexOf("<" + tag + ">")) + html.substring(html.indexOf("</" + tag + ">") + tag.length() + 3, html.length());
```

whole code

```
public static String extractTagContent(String html, String tag) {
    String list = "";
    while (html.contains("</" + tag + ">")) {
        list += html.substring(html.indexOf("<" + tag + ">") + tag.length() + 2, html.indexOf("</" + tag + ">")) + "\n";
        html = html.substring(0, html.indexOf("<" + tag + ">")) + html.substring(html.indexOf("</" + tag + ">") + tag.length() + 3, html.length());
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: How could i modify the code so that it will work in situations like <name> brian <job> </name> evil scientist</job> And i want the same results prints out brain and the evil scientist thanks for help the code works, but not in this situation

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to fix what's generating these out-of-order tags instead?